# Can an AVL tree has the same value for a key in different nodes?

Tags: c++, c, binary-tree

I don't know how to ask this but I will try.

so I've implemented an AVL tree and it works perfectly with the complexity O(log n).

I want to apply some features on it, but in order to do so, I have to allow my keys to have a same value at some point (which means no unique key). In other words, if i add a key with the number 4 (key = 4), I can make an Insert to another key with the number 4 (another key = 4).

Eventually my tree would be, X in root, left sub tree has values less than X, right sub tree has values greater or **EQUAL** to X. (Or obviously can allow the **EQUAL** to the left sub tree instead to the right).

My question is, I understand this would still be considered a binary search tree, but would it still be considered an AVL tree? with the complexity of O(log n) in all its operations? I mean this EQUAL thing would **NOT** affect anything? or am I missing something !?

Thank you very much guys

Comment: In general, this should be no problem, you just have to think about the semantics of the lookup, update or delete operations (if available). Should all nodes with the same key be affected? Or any node? Or a specific order?

Comment: Thanks as well @Ctx , I totally forgot about the deletion part, but yeah I can make it work in my favor.

Answer (score 3):

The AVL tree doesn't require the uniqueness of the keys. The only operation it requires from the type of the elements is the operation <, and that is a valid operation even in case of the keys you can consider equal. You are right, the left subtree would consist of the keys that are less then, but the right subtree items would have values that are "not less than" (which logically should be greater or equal, but does not require the element even to have a notion of equality or greatness).

Regarding C++, the std::multiset doesn't require the uniqueness of the keys and may be implemented as an AVL tree.

The rest depends on your implementation.